# Android phonegap and SockJS

Tags: android, sockets, cordova, websocket, sockjs

Is there any way to get Android working with SockJs for socket connections in an app packaged in Phonegap? At the moment I have the following code that works on iOS but fails in Android because of the file:/// restriction for socket connections in android.

```
var sock = MyEnt.connect('servicename', 'http://socket.api.somewhere.be/api', {debug: true});
var entity_plays = sock.subscribe('plays');
entity_plays.on("play", function(data, msg) {
       //Do something with data
       console.log(data,msg)
}, {backlog: 10});
```

I have changed the service names for client privacy but as the above code works in the iOS PG version (and desktop browsers for that matter), that shouldn't matter. 
The MyEnt object is a small wrapper containing custom functions in the SockJS class, but again works perfectly on iOS

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SockJS should work correctly from phonegap. Either via native web sockets or xhr-streaming. Look for `file://` in [documentation](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client).

Comment: I have looked and there it says "Sometimes you may want to serve your html from "file://" address - for development or if you're using PhoneGap or similar technologies. But due to the Cross Origin Policy files served from "file://" have no Origin, and that means some of SockJS transports won't work." So I am unsure how to modify the code so that it will work. Could you help me a litlte further along please?

Comment: That comment was about xhr-polling when your server requires cookies, AFAIR. Normally, sockjs should use native websockets and that should work fine. All you should need to do is to have a good whitelist of allowed domains for phonegap and that's it.

Comment: Well that's the odd part. My access origin is set to everything (<access origin=".*" />) I know this is a security issue but for testing reasons I thought that was most practical. Could there be another reason why it fails?

Comment: Never mind, the dot (.) was the problem! thanks a lot for the help!